# Hibernate mapping field as a primary and foreign key

Tags: java, hibernate

So I have simple relation client with his type. Since every entity is identified by id and source system id I have everywhere composite keys. How to save automaticly type when I am saving client entity?

Client class:

```
public class Client implements Serializable {

     @EmbeddedId
     private ClientKey primaryKey;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumns({
       @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "client_type", referencedColumnName = "dict_id"),
       @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "client_own_id", referencedColumnName = "dict_own_id"),
     })
     private Type type;

 }
```

primary key

```
@Embeddable
public class ClientKey implements Serializable {

     @Column(name = "client_id")
     private String clientId;
     @Column(name = "client_own_id")
     private String clientOwnId;

 }
```

type class

```
@Entity
public class Type implements Serializable {

     @EmbeddedId
     private DictKey primaryKey; //dict_id and dict_own_id

     ...
 }
```

When i am running code:

```
clientRepo.create(client); //client contains setted type as typeRepo.getById(1).
```

After transaction I have saved client but client_type column contains null. From what I understood the problem is insertable/updatable = false. So I setted

```
 @JoinColumn(insertable = true, updatable = true, name = "client_type", referencedColumnName = "dict_id"), //true since I want to have updated client_type field
 @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "client_own_id", referencedColumnName = "dict_own_id"), //false since I have this field in primary key already
```

then I am getting:

```
Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed
```

so I am setting both to true:

```
 @JoinColumn(insertable = true, updatable = true, name = "client_type", referencedColumnName = "dict_id"), //true since I want to have saved client_type field
 @JoinColumn(insertable = true, updatable = true, name = "client_own_id", referencedColumnName = "dict_own_id"), //true because I dont know why :D
```

then:

```
 repeated column in mapping for entity: Client column: client_own_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

I have no more ideas...

EDIT:
below looks fine except that when I have relation to client entity:

```
 @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "client_id", referencedColumnName = "client_id"),
    @JoinColumn(insertable = false, updatable = false, name = "client_own_id", referencedColumnName = "client_own_id"),
})
  private Client client;
```

I'am getting

```
Unable to find column with logical name: client_own_id in client
```

Comment: [quote] After transaction I have saved client but client_status column contains null [end quote] where's client_status column at all in your code?

Comment: sry I misspelled. status = type. I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you have here is a case where Client has a complex Key which is partially derived from it's association to Type.

In this case I think the mappings should be as below:

The Entity class:

```
public class Client implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClientKey primaryKey;

    @MapsId("type") //maps to type in the EmbdeddedId
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_type", referencedColumnName = "dict_id"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_own_id", referencedColumnName = "dict_own_id")
    })
    private Type type;
 }
```

The EmbeddedId:

```
@Embeddable
public class ClientKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="client_id")
    private String clientId;

    @Embedded
    private DictKey type;

    //...
}
```

Comment: Unable to find column with logical name: client_own_id in client ;/
embedded dict key in primary key should't have overriden names to client_type, client_own_id ?

Comment: Is this a question, a statement of fact, an error message or what?

Comment: Thats error. I changed every occurrence of client_own_id to client_own_id2 in client and primary key and it still fail onclient_own_id. So relation between any entity and client is now braked becasue relation dont see client_own_id column